Dynamic resizing based on screen size in Flutter
I'm switching from a third party tool that I made a template for to Flutter to become independent from that third party tool.
I have a lot of icons, some syncfusion gauges and texts on my screen and I've now come to the point where for the first part all elements are there and at a position where I'm happy with when testing inside a Google Pixel emulator.
I have then realized that when trying it on a physical tablet or testing it in a browser and resizing the window, things start moving weirdly (kinda expected of course)
I tried implementing dynamic resizing with some help from ChatGPT and it ended up using a lot of wrapping in SizedBoxes, Flexibles and Containers together with screen size calculations that were kinda painful to make especially because every damn element needs a different factor which ended up looking like this for size calculations:
double screenWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
double screenHeight = constraints.maxHeight;

double factor = 15;

double areaFactor = screenWidth * screenHeight / 1000000;

double fontSizeCenterLarge = areaFactor * 35;
double fontSizeCenterMedium = areaFactor * 25;
double fontSizeCenterSmall = areaFactor * 12;

double gaugeCenterSize = areaFactor * factor;
double gaugeIconSize = gaugeCenterSize * 2;
double fontSizeGaugeLarge = areaFactor * factor;
double fontSizeGaugeMedium = areaFactor * factor;
double fontSizeGaugeSmall = areaFactor * factor;
double gaugeLabelOffsetLarge = areaFactor * factor;
double gaugeLabelOffsetMedium = areaFactor * factor;
double gaugeLabelOffsetSmall = areaFactor * factor;

An element for example would have looked like this then:
Container(
  width: gaugeCenterSize * 9.2,
  height: gaugeCenterSize * 9.2,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      end: Alignment.topCenter,
      colors: [
        Colors.black87,
        Colors.white30
      ],
      stops: [0.0, 1.0],
    ),
  ),
),

this:
SizedBox(
  width: gaugeIconSize,
  height: gaugeIconSize,
  child: Image.asset(
  ccEngaged
    ? 'assets/images/ccon.png'
    : 'assets/images/ccoff.png',
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
),

or like this:
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.loose,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Text(
      gear.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: fontSizeCenterMedium,
        color: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'Prime',
      ),
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),
  ),
),

I figured these would then resize the elements proportionally to the screen size, but they didn't, they even shifted around in some cases and texts started clipping into invisible borders. I'd really like things to move and resize properly and proportionally on any platform since this is planned to be used on desktop/web and mobile.
It also feels like there would be a simpler way or something that gives more control over how things actually behave when resized, that I don't know about (yet)

if you want everything to be scaled proportionally simply wrap your entire layout with FittedBox but believe me - it will look ugly

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

@RandalSchwartz I'm not planning to allow re-use of this and have a license acquired from SyncFusion

@pskink Well "looking ugly" is exactly what I'd need to avoid because the project's point is to visualize a game's values pretty much in real-time (currently requesting every 50ms) through a REST API endpoint

if you scale everything you will get something like the tablet from  https://i.tst.sh/1685589984433963.png (this is what i mean by "ugly") - for more refer to https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/ that gives more hints to follow

@pskink That link seems to be talking about exactly what my issue is; that png is basically my issue, I can make it look amazing and perfect on the emulator/phone, all space well used etc, I switch to the tablet and everything is "small in comparison" yknow, just all this empty space as with that png; thanks for that hint!

You don't want pixel perfect. You want responsive. And Flutter has many amazing tools to make responsive layouts, like LayoutBuilder for breakpoints, and Flex (Row/Column) widgets for adaptive sizing. Figma and other mockup tools are generally very poor at representing this... the best tool to preview layout designs is Flutter itself (thanks to hot reload).  Oh, and familiarize yourself with less-referenced layout widgets like FittedBox, FractionallySizedBox, AspectRatio, Spacer, Wrap, and learn when to use double.infinity for a width or height rather than querying with MediaQuery for the useless screen size.  This is a great writeup from the author of Boxy on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/.

Well if you say "You don't want pixel perfect" am I wrong using Flutter then maybe? My project is first and foremost an application to visualize values from a REST API endpoint; and I'd like those to be pretty pixel perfect or at least the same readability on a big tablet, desktop screen or a smaller android phone or mini-display. That is the idea behind it. The values are almost live since I request them every 50ms (as of right now) so it should also be fast, I first tried it with MAUI but that was just too much pain to get into so I opted for web. Should I look into a different language?

Yes.  You want responsive.  Not scaled.  See the article I linked.

Ah I see, well then, thanks for the article, I'll take a look at it!

you can use flutter_screenutils instead, it is perfect.

No.  That package is specifically trying to do the wrong thing.  See my other answer.

For dynamic resizing based on the screen sizes in flutter here are a few approaches that might help simplify and improve your solution:

Use MediaQuery for Dynamic Screen Size Calculation
Responsive Layouts Using LayoutBuilder
Flexible Widgets and FittedBox for Scaling
Using flutter_screenutil for Proportional Scaling
Using FractionallySizedBox for Flexible Resizing

MediaQuery for Dynamic Screen Size Calculation
Use MediaQuery to obtain the current screen’s width, height, and device pixel ratio. This way, you can ensure that the layout scales dynamically based on the actual device screen size.
For Example:
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double devicePixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

double factor = screenWidth / 375; // 375 is a reference width (e.g., iPhone 6)

double fontSize = factor * 16; // Adjust font size dynamically
double iconSize = factor * 24; // Adjust icon size dynamically

With this approach you can easily scale your UI for different screen sizes.
for further details: MediaQuery
Responsive Layouts Using LayoutBuilder
Layout builder provides you the dimensions of the parent widget, then using those dimensions to scale the child widgets.
Forexample:
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    double screenWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
    double screenHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
    double factor = screenWidth / 375;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: screenWidth * 0.5,
          height: screenHeight * 0.2,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(
            'Responsive Container',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: factor * 20),
          ),
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.access_alarm,
          size: factor * 40,
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);

now the child widgets will adjust automatically on different screen sizes.
for further details on LayoutBuilder.
Flexible Widgets and FittedBox for Scaling
Using Flexible and FittedBox will make sure the widgets resize proportionally without providing the size manually.
Flexible widget adjusts the widget elements based on the available space, while FittedBox make sure that the content fits with in the available bounds.
ForExample:
Flexible(
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Text(
      'Responsive Text',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

Now the FittedBox will automatically scales the content within the available space.
For further details on Flexible.
For further details on FittedBox.
flutter_screenutil for Proportional Scaling
flutter_screenutil provides an easy way to define the widget size ratios that scale proportionally to the screen’s dimensions.
for example:
Container(
  width: 200.w,  // Scales width proportionally
  height: 100.h,  // Scales height proportionally
  child: Text(
    'Responsive Text',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.sp),  // Scales font size proportionally
  ),
) 

for further details visit this page: flutter_screenutils
FractionallySizedBox for Flexible Resizing
FractionallySizedBox ensures that the element's size is proportional to the parent widget size by defining the width and height proportional to the parent's size.
For Example:
FractionallySizedBox(
  widthFactor: 0.8, // 80% of the parent width
  heightFactor: 0.3, // 30% of the parent height
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Text('I resize with the parent'),
  ),
)

for further details: FractionallySizedBox

So I used LayoutBuilder to get a factor for positioning and used screenutil for resizing and have the following outcome:
https://imgur.com/a/5WMDiJC
The first picture is on an android tablet (Galaxy Tab I think A2?) while the second picture on my android phone (Google Pixel 8)
Why is it so small on the Pixel while basically perfect on the tablet? Why don't they resize so they size stays the same on a different sized screen?

so it depends on the designSize that you have passed to the screenUtils while initializing the material app, I suggest first go with the default designSize of the screenUtils and check on both devices and also if possible please let me know what design size you are using?
